# -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true set, but build still errors on test failure

Tags: maven, unit-testing, jenkins

I have two different freestyle Jenkins jobs that are kicked off like this (build commands lifted from the job logs):

`mvn -Dcloudbees.private.release.repository.off=true -Dcloudbees.private.snapshot.plugin.repository.off=true -Dcloudbees.private.release.plugin.repository.off=true -Dcloudbees.central.repository.off=true -Dcloudbees.private.snapshot.repository.off=true clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -V -Dcheckstyle.skip=true -Dpmd.skip=true -Dgpg.skip=true -B -e`

and

`mvn clean install cobertura:cobertura -DallTests -Dcobertura.report.format=xml -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -V -Dcheckstyle.skip=true -Dpmd.skip=true`

They end like this (respectively):

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project gora-core: There are test failures.`

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project wildfly-domain-management: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed:`

All my searching tells me that `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` should do the trick, so I'm stymied.

Note that I don't have write access to these projects; I'm simply trying to compile in preparation for SonarQube analysis.

**UPDATE1**

I turned out to have 3 jobs (and counting) with these symptoms. For the record, they are:

1. [ActiveMQ](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq.git) (not previously listed)
2. [Wildfly Core](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core)
3. [Gora](http://git.apache.org/gora.git/)

The addition of `-B` to the ActiveMQ job (the others already had it) moved it forward to the point of an actual compile failure. Unfortunately, the job still hasn't succeeded, so I can't be sure that `-B` actually fixed the job.

I tried Gora locally with the same result as on Jenkins.

**UPDATE2**

I've since found `<testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>` in the main Gora pom, but grep tells me `testFailureIgnore` is nowhere in the Wildfly Core project.

**UPDATE3**

The Wildfly Core failure can apparently be chalked up to a bug in [Surefire 2.17](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1091)

Comment: FWIW, I see two different versions of the surefire plugin in the posted error messages.  The latest version of Surefire is 2.19.  Can the versions be updated?

Comment: I don't have access to update the poms. I'm in a readonly position, trying to perform SonarQube analysis on nemo.sonarqube.org.

Comment: I would also try running Maven in debug mode (`-X`) to see what Maven thinks that property is before it starts actually running the tests.  If someone has hardcoded the value in the POM (e.g. `<testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>`) then it could be ignoring the command line value you're providing.

Comment: Both jobs show `true` throughout their logs (altho one does contain `<testFailureIgnore default-value="false">${maven.test.failure.ignore}</testFailureIgnore>` but I'm reading that to mean that the value supplied on the command line should be applied)

Comment: That's how I'd read it too.  I was wondering if we'd see something like `<testFailureIgnore default-value="false">false</testFailureIgnore>`.  What happens if you run the build without Jenkins?  And - are the Jenkins projects FreeStyle or Maven?  Stephen Connolly of the Maven team [considers Jenkins Maven job type evil](http://javaadventure.blogspot.com/2013/11/jenkins-maven-job-type-considered-evil.html).

Comment: First make using the same version of maven-surefire-pugin in your build otherwise it's hard.

Comment: @user944849 please post your thoughts about `<testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>` as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running Maven in debug mode (-X) to see what Maven thinks that property is before it starts actually running the tests. If someone or something has hardcoded the value in the POM (e.g. `<testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>`) then it could be ignoring the command line value you're providing.

Also make sure the Jenkins job is not a Maven job type.  Stephen Connolly wrote a blog post about why the [Jenkins Maven job type is evil](http://javaadventure.blogspot.com/2013/11/jenkins-maven-job-type-considered-evil.html) and he explicitly mentioned that the test ignore toggle is one item modified by the plugin under the covers.  One of the comments on that post is:

> sorry testFailureIgnore is false not skip is true..., e.g.
>
> `<configuration>
>     <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
>   <configuration>`
>
> which will ensure that the module's tests cannot be skipped... except when the Maven job type is playing fast and loose with its auto-magic

Comment: These are already freestyle jobs. I've edited the OP to reflect that.